# How do I provide specialization of template function for a templated type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function that I'd like to provide a specialization for, in order to handle `boost::optional<T>`. However, I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax for this scenario, if I want to allow my specialization to handle all types of `boost::optional<T>`, instead of a specific one like `boost::optional<int>`.

Here's a compilable example:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{}

// This works.
template<>
void foo<int>(const int& t)
{}

// This works.
template<>
void foo<boost::optional<int>>(const boost::optional<int>& t)
{}

// What to do in this case??
// template <typename U>
// void foo<boost::optional<U>>(const boost::optional<U>& t)
// {}

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't specialize. Provide an overload instead.

```
template <typename U>
void foo(const boost::optional<U>& t)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partial specialize template function. But you can do it for `class`

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    struct foo_impl
    {
        void operator () (const T&) const {};
    }

    template <>
    struct foo_impl<int> // Full specialization for int
    {
        void operator () (int) const {};
    }

    template <>
    struct foo_impl<boost::optional<int>> // Full specialization for boost::optional<int>
    {
        void operator () (const boost::optional<int>&) const {};
    }

    template <typename T>
    struct foo_impl<boost::optional<T>> // Partial specialization for boost::optional<T>
    {
        void operator () (const boost::optional<T>&) const {};
    }

}

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
    detail::foo_impl<T>{}(t); // Forward to correct struct
}
```

else you can provide overload (which may be simpler)

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T&) {}

void foo(int) {}

void foo(const boost::optional<int>&) {}

template <typename T>
void foo(const boost::optional<T>&) {}
```

Note about the overload method:

```
- `foo(42)` and `foo<int>(42)` won't call the same function
- and similarly, with `boost::optional<int> opt_i;`,  
    `foo(opt_i)`, `foo<int>(opt_i)` and `foo<boost::optional<int>>(opt_i)`
     will call 3 different functions.
```

Comment: I was just about to ask a followup question about how I can do this when the return type of the function contains the template parameter, and there is no parameter list to the function. Since the return type does not participate in overload resolution, I can't apply the other answer in this scenario. However, it looks like this might work for this second problem...